# display ProgressBar ontop of ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

Asking the Simplest Question, I have searched a lot related to my problem but didn't find any solution. I Have a layout in an Android application in which I'm using a `listview` with `progressbar`. All the task in doing in **AsyncTask** class. I want to Show the progress bar in centre of the activity before loading a list. Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong or what changes are required for this solution. Thanks in Advance.

**How I tried**

**activity_main:**

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class GettingAlerts extends ListActivity {

// Initialization
IPAddress ipAddressObject = new IPAddress();
public static String GETTING_ALERTS_URL = "http://"
        + IPAddress.IP_Address.toString()
        + "/MyServices/Alerts/AlertService.svc/gettingAllAlerts";

// TAGS
public static String TAG_NAME = "GetAllAlertsResult";
public static String TAG_ALERT_TITLE = "alertTitle";
public static String TAG_ALERT_DESCRIPTION = "alertDescription";
public static String TAG_ALERT_OWNER = "alertOwner";
public static String TAG_ALERT_DEADLINE = "alertDeadline";
static String Serv_Response = "";

ArrayList<Alerts> alertsList;
ProgressBar pg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alert_activity_list);

    pg = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    // setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    alertsList = new ArrayList<Alerts>();
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

    new GettingAlertsList().execute();
}

private class GettingAlertsList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // LinearLayout linlaHeaderProgress = (LinearLayout)
        // findViewById(R.id.linlaHeaderProgress);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(GETTING_ALERTS_URL);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        try {
            Serv_Response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (Serv_Response != null) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(Serv_Response);
                JSONArray quiz = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_NAME);

                for (int i = 0; i < quiz.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = quiz.getJSONObject(i);
                    String alert_title = c.getString(TAG_ALERT_TITLE);
                    String alert_owner = c.getString(TAG_ALERT_OWNER);
                    String alert_desc = c.getString(TAG_ALERT_DESCRIPTION);
                    String alert_dealdine = c.getString(TAG_ALERT_DEADLINE);

                    Alerts alertObject = new Alerts();
                    alertObject.setAlertTitle(alert_title);
                    alertObject.setAlertDescription(alert_desc);
                    alertObject.setAlertDeadline(alert_dealdine);
                    alertObject.setAlertOwner(alert_owner);

                    alertsList.add(alertObject);
                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        CustomAlertListAdapter adapter = new CustomAlertListAdapter(
                GettingAlerts.this, alertsList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        pg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}

}
```

**Image**

[image]

As you could see the **progressbar** is at the top of the activity. I want that **progressbar** in `center` of the activity before loading the List.

Comment: Have you considered using a `ProgressDialog` instead?

Comment: thanks for your response @MikeM. Don,t you think progressbar (Circle) would be an appropriate solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

Remove `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` and add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change visibility to display/hide progress bar. You might need to set to change some attributes like style:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:progress="0"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you require Sub layout to display/hide only ProgressBar?

Comment: @PareshMayani display/hide?? This will center the progress bar and will cover the list until loaded if needed.

Comment: i.e. Visible/Gone. No need of sublayout because it's increasing layout hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I assume currently you have used `LinearLayout` but instead get `RelativeLayout` in XML and change order of widgets as below and remove `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` from ProgressBar.

```
<RelativeLayout
  ...
  ...>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why it's not possible with LinearLayout?

Comment: Why do you want LinearLayout if it can be doable easily by using RelativeLayout. I would say its bit tricky if you use LinearLayout.